# Xamarin iOS simulator build

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

Does anyone know if Xamarin build for iOS simulator is somehow different from regular Xcode simulator build?

In other words is Xamarin simulator build "clean" native build?

Comment: possible to explain what exactly is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [Xamarin docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/under_the_hood/architecture/#Overview):

> When you compile any Xamarin platform application, the Mono C# (or F#)
>   compiler will run and will compile your C# and F# code into Microsoft
>   Intermediate Language (MSIL). If you are running a Xamarin.Android, a
>   Xamarin.Mac application, or even a Xamarin.iOS application on the
>   simulator, the .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR) compiles the MSIL
>   using a Just in Time (JIT) compiler. At runtime this is compiled into
>   a native code, which can run on the correct architecture for your
>   application.
>
> However, there is a security restriction on iOS, set by Apple, which
>   disallows the execution of dynamically generated code on a device. To
>   ensure that we adhere to these safety protocols, Xamarin.iOS instead
>   uses an Ahead of Time (AOT) compiler to compile the managed code. This
>   produces a native iOS binary, optionally optimized with LLVM for
>   devices, that can be deployed on Apple’s ARM-based processor.